# Can't create a table with mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create in MYSQL table using SHELL.

Code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books(¬
 book_id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,¬
 author_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,¬
 title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,¬
 year INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1900,¬
 language VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'es',¬
 cover_url VARCHAR(500),¬
 price DOUBLE(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 10.0,¬
 sellable TINYINT(1) DEFAULT,¬
 description TEXT¬
);¬
```

and it's giving me this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '¬
 book_id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,¬
 author_id INTEGER UN' at line 1
```

Comment: What is this `¬` character?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I changed the INTEGER for INT and deleted the ¬ and now I have this error 

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',
 description TEXT
)' at line 9

Comment: I'm using the last version, I just downloaded today, this is the version 8.0.18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at second-last line, you forgot to give a default value to `sellable`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books( 
    book_id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    author_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    year INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1900,
    language VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'es',
    cover_url VARCHAR(500),
    price DOUBLE(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10.0',
    sellable TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
    description TEXT NOT NULL);
```